# ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I want to export my dataset. When running the below code I'm getting the following error:

`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Code :

```
list_kalimat = []
nomor_kalimat = 1

# open file in read mode
with open('SINGGALANG.tsv', encoding='UTF-8') as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter='\t', quotechar=None)
    
    # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
    for row in csv_reader:
        # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
        if len(row) == 0:
            nomor_kalimat += 1 
        else:
            tmp_row= row
            tmp_row.append(nomor_kalimat)
            list_kalimat.append(tmp_row)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(list_kalimat, columns=['token', 'entitas bernama', 'kalimat'])
dataset.to_csv(dataset, index=False, columns=['token'])
```

Comment: the first argument of `datase.to_csv()` must be the path where you want to save your dataframe, not `dataset`. Actually you don't have to pass `dataset` as a argument at all. You can find the documentation of this method here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: do you mean like this : 
`dataset.to_csv('E:/', index=False, columns=['token'])`
but it gives an error : `Permission denied: 'E:/'` @TajinderSingh

Comment: If you want to save the file in your current directory just write "my_csv.csv", otherwise write the full path